# javascript: find overlapping circles in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, geometry, overlap

How can I fix this code to properly detect overlapping circles?
The first circle is appointed by testing the location of the starting point. This first circle should be the basis of the overlapping circle map. Now, it only works if the tested circles overlap in a non-branching line...

(individual circles come as [x,y,radius])

```
var circles = [
    [6, 19, 1],
    [6, 11, 4],
    [8, 17, 3],
    [19, 19, 2],
    [19, 11, 4],
    [15, 7, 6],
    [12, 19, 4]
];
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
var start = [10, 19];
var starts = false;
var overlapping = [];

var isInside = function(point, list, check, push) {
    var temp = list.filter(function(item) { return Math.pow(item[0] - point[0], 2) + Math.pow(item[1] - point[1], 2) < item[2] * item[2] });
    if (push) { overlapping = overlapping.concat(temp) };
    return temp.length > 0
};

starts = isInside(start, circles, starts, true);

var overlappingCirclesTest = function() {
    if (j < circles.length && overlapping.length > 0) {
        var i = overlapping.length - 1;
        var r0 = overlapping[i][2];
        var r1 = circles[j][2];
        var x0 = overlapping[i][0];
        var x1 = circles[j][0];
        var y0 = overlapping[i][1];
        var y1 = circles[j][1];
        if (Math.hypot(x0 - x1, y0 - y1) <= (r0 + r1)) {
            overlapping.push(circles[j]);
            circles.splice(circles.indexOf(circles[j]), 1);
            j = 0;
            overlappingCirclesTest();
        }
        j++;
        overlappingCirclesTest();
    }
}
overlappingCirclesTest();
```

EDIT: for clarification: we have an array of potentially overlapping circles and two points, start and finish. We want to produce a path of overlapping circles, starting with the one with start in it and ending with the one with end in it. There can be several potential paths, we just want to know if there's any path at all.

Comment: Do you mean circles that overlap each other or circles that overlap the starting point?

Comment: Overlap each other, but the first circle to start the overlapping is the one with the starting point in it. Note that there can be more than one circle with the starting point in it.

Comment: And then from there you want all circles that overlap each other in a group? Not just the ones that overlap the starting circle?

Comment: Hmm yes, I think so. Basically, from the 'circles' array I want to filter out the overlapping circles ( array 'overlapping'), but at least one of those has to have the starting point in it.

Comment: Do you care of the algorithm is O(N^2) or what is the maximum set size of circles we're talking about here?

Comment: Realistically I guess there can be thousands of circles in in 'circles' array.

Comment: So with this kind of algorithm it will be pretty slow building up the index, so you won't want to do it very often. The search is really fast but the index is not, which means you'll want to keep it as state and every time a new circle is added you'll want to just check the overlapping for those new circles which is O(N). If a circle is deleted or updated then you'll want to do a search, remove the circle then update all of the previously overlapping circles in the group.

Comment: The circles array can be just about any size, but let's assume it will not be changed once its set.

Answer (score 0):

So here's a very basic collision checking system. Whenever you update, run Collision and pass the parameters of the circle you are checking collision for.

```
function Collision (x, y, r) {
    for (i=0; i<circles.length; i++) {
        //Distance formula
        if (Math.sqrt((x-circles[i].x)(x-circles[i].x) + (y-circles[i].y)(y-circles[i].y) < r) {
            return true;
    }
}
```

Here's an example of a circle object, and how to call it:

```
function Circle() {
    this.x = Math.random()*100;
    this.y = Math.random()*100;
    this.r = Math.random()*50;

    this.update = function() {
        if (Collision(this.x, this.y, this.r) {
          console.log("circle collided with another circle");
        }
    }
};
```

Additionally, you can check out the source of a project I created that uses lots of circles and checks the collision between all of them and the player. http://betaio.bitballoon.com

Comment: Added clarification to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more complete answer, I didn't attempt to visualize the circles so its hard for me to be sure this is totally correct but I think this should get you closer.

I think the algorithm is O(N^2) so it won't be fast but the strategy I took is to build up an index over every single overlapping circle and then find one using the point, then essentially recurse through the overlapping index to find all of the cirlces it is associated with in a group.

Here is the code:

```
function circleCollisionDetect (c1, c2) {
  var dx = c1[0] - c2[0]
  var dy = c1[1] - c2[1]
  var distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
  return distance < c1[2] + c2[2]
}

function circlePointCollisionDetect (p, c) {
  const dx = p[0] - c[0]
  const dy = p[1] - c[1]
  const distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
  return distance < c[2]
}

function search (i, circles, index) {
  const group = []
  function follow(i) {
    if (!~group.indexOf(i)) {
      group.push(i)
      const overlaps = index[i]
      for (let x = 0, n = overlaps.length; x < n; x++) {
        follow(overlaps[x])
      }
    }
  }
  follow(i)
  return group
}

const circles = [
  [6, 19, 1],
  [6, 11, 4],
  [8, 17, 3],
  [19, 19, 2],
  [19, 11, 4],
  [15, 7, 6],
  [12, 19, 4]
]
const overlaps = []
const p = [10, 19]

// Find one that overlaps the starting point
const c = circles.find(c => circlePointCollisionDetect(p, c))
const start = circles.indexOf(c)

// Build an index of all overlapping circles
for (let a = 0, n = circles.length; a < n; a++) {
  for (let b = 0; b < n; b++) {
    const c1 = circles[a]
    const c2 = circles[b]
    if (c1 === c2) continue;
    if (!overlaps[a]) overlaps[a] = []
    if (circleCollisionDetect(c1, c2)) overlaps[a].push(b)
  }
}

// Next search through the index recursively for unique overlapping circles
const overlapping = search(start, circles, overlaps)

console.log('start:', start)
console.log('index:', overlaps)
console.log('overlapping:', overlapping)
```

Which prints:

```
start: 2
index: [ [ 2 ], [ 2, 5 ], [ 0, 1, 6 ], [], [ 5 ], [ 1, 4 ], [ 2 ] ]
overlapping: [ 2, 0, 1, 5, 4, 6 ]
```

So basically they are all overlapping each other except for `[19, 19, 2]`, is that correct?

Comment: Yeah but how to loop over the circles correctly? I want to create a branching tree of overlapping circles, and at least one of those must have the starting point in it.

Comment: Updated with search algorithm

Comment: I wanted to run it, but it throws error 'overlaps is not defined'. Also, I forgot to add we have an end point too, and just like start point it has to be in one of the overlapping circles. It's basically about building a roadmap of overlapping circles, with starting circle containing start point and the final circle containing the end point.

Comment: Added clarification to my original post.

Comment: Ok try again, I messed it up when renaming something before posting it here. It doesn't yet handle the end point but it should be able to.

The answer to the question though I think is just that to solve the problem you need to build up an index of all overlaps. Then you can use that overlap index to solve your problem, or any question related to overlapping circles.

Comment: By "roadmap" do you mean you want to find a path from start to end?

Comment: If so... that is a fundamentally different problem to solve and will require a totally different algorithm. But the good news is that my answer is still needed, its the first part of the puzzle. The first thing you would do would be to build up the indexes like I have done here then to use a path finding algorithm to traverse that index. An easy and efficient path finding algorithm would be A* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm). 

You would simply replace the search function I provided here with a implementation of A* that searches the index from start to finish.